# Paypal payment-gateway to implement Refund & Virtual Credits

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-adaptive-payments, credits

We want to integrate Paypal for Australian country,  Here we were trying to use Website Payment Pro method to do refund to customer credit / debit cards by using DoNonReferencedCredit API of Website Payment Pro.But this API is not working in Australia.

In our application, We have used Refund method of Adaptive Payment Gateway. By using Adaptive payment gateway while customer doing payment it creating transaction id (Pay Key) with every associated transaction. Here in our website, customer can ask for full refund or credit their amount for which they have made transactions on checkout previously.

1) For Full refund, Amount can be refunded by using Refund() method of adaptive payment system within period of 90 days with that transaction.

2) For Credit Amount option We are saving the credited amount with customer Id in our database.customer have credit amount as a balance in their account according to saved value in our DB. For further Shopping on website, Customer can pay amount at checkout page either using their credit (Balance) Amount which is virtually store in DB not on paypal, In this case we can't create reference transaction id (pay key) with Adaptive payment system so if customer again asked for full refund with these non-referenced transaction(Amount paid virtually), then Refund() method is not able to perform or do refunds because transaction is not recorded with paypal, there balance is virtually on Primary paypal holding account. Do we have any way to refund() amount of customer to their credit cards from primary pay-pal holding account for non-referenced (Virtual Credited) transactions.

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution for this? We have a similar situation.